# I need to do the following report in Jasper - Ireport

Tags: jasper-reports

[image: The following image depicts the report I want]

I need a group two columns, one is BigDecimal and the other Date

Comment: And, if possible, could you explain what you Can't accomplish right now? Maybe your dataset would be usefull as well

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to do simple table with 5 columns (ID, Value, Date, Value, Date) and get all these data from db by one SQL query? I think it should be the easiest way how to handle with this problem

Create a query which will fill your rows and send it into dataset. Then create table based on this dataset with 5 columns. After it create 2 variables `value1_total` and `value2_total`, where you sum the total numbers, and these insert into table footer as total line.

The SQL query can be possibly something as join two subqueries, which will group required data by date, and join them on date or id

Hope this helps